# Android - Spinner's data disappears

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, spinner

I have an Android activity which displays a spinner populated with data from a database. The onCreate() is listed here:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fuel_entry);

    vehicleDataCursor = VehicleDataProvider.getVehicles();
    startManagingCursor(vehicleDataCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{REGISTRATION_NO_COLUMN, DESCRIPTION_COLUMN}; 
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.vehicle_db_row_registration_number, R.id.vehicle_db_row_description};

    vehicleAdapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.vehicle_spinner_row, vehicleDataCursor, from, to);

    vehicleSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    vehicleSpinner.setAdapter(vehicleAdapter);

mileageEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fuel_entry_mileage_edit_text);

fuelAmountEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fuel_entry_fuel_edit_text);

fuelEntryOkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fuel_entry_ok_button);
fuelEntryOkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String registrationNumber = "";
    Cursor cc = (Cursor)(vehicleSpinner.getSelectedItem());
    if (cc != null)
    {
    registrationNumber = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndexOrThrow(REGISTRATION_NO_COLUMN));
        if(FuelUseDataProvider.addFuelUp(registrationNumber, Integer.parseInt(mileageEntry.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(fuelAmountEntry.getText().toString()), System.currentTimeMillis()) != DATABASE_INSERT_ERROR_CODE)
            {
            showMPGDialog(registrationNumber);
            }
            else
            {
          //do error handling
            }
            cc.close();
       }
}
});}
```

It works fine but has a minor problem - when the user fills in the form and clicks the fuelEntryOkButton, a dialog is display as intended but the spinner is empited of its data. If I removed the cc.close(); line, the problem goes away. Obviously I'd like to close the cursor when I've finished with it. I can't understand this - it is vehicleDataCursor which is providing data for the cursor, not cc.

Any ideas why my Spinner loses its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor cc = (Cursor)(vehicleSpinner.getSelectedItem());
```

As far as I understand it, when you do this you are simply getting a reference to the Cursor associated with the Spinner. In other words, a reference to `vehicleDataCursor`.

When you close `cc`, you're effectively closing `vehicleDataCursor`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Perfect sense. And it works - I can get the data I need using vehicleDataSpinner. cc is not required. Barry